# jQuery form validation not working with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

Before using bootstrap, my jQuery form validation worked. Now it's not working.
Help with this problem much appreciated. Thanks!

Here's some of my code...

My form and script call:

```
<div class="form1">
            <!-- registration form, which is validated by script bellow -->
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id='registerform'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"
                            placeholder="Enter email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd"
                            placeholder="Enter password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Confirm
                        Password:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwdcnf"
                            placeholder="Enter password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- form validation script -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/formValidation.js"></script>
```

My jQuery:

```
    $('#registerform').validate({
    rules:{
        errorClass: "error",
        'email':{
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        'pwd':{
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        'pwdcnf':{
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    },
    messages:{
        'pwd':{
            required:"This field is required",
            minlength:"Your password must be at least 5 character long"
        },
        'pwdcnf':{
            required:"This field is required",
            minlength:"Your password must be at least 5 character long",
            equalTo:"Your password does not match"
        }
    }
});
```

on top:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- import of bootstrap css and js code -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/background.css"> <!-- my css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--these two scripts allow the use of the jQuery form validation plug in.-->
<!--the form validation script is lower down bellow the registration form -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

I'm guessing that the bootstrap javascript file is conflicting some how with jQuery and my validation?

Comment: If you were to comment out `<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` does it work?

Comment: include jquery script reference before bootstrap

Comment: I tried both commenting out src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></scrip‌​t> and changed the order of the scripts. No luck.

Comment: also move ur formvalidation.js after the jquery.validate reference. make sure jquery is loaded before ur validation scripts. check the console for any errors

Comment: I've tried all of these suggestions and still no luck. I did get this three times in the console though... WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Experiments' did not find a matching property.

Comment: "Not working" means exactly what?

Comment: You've incorrectly put `errorClass` inside of the `rules` object.  The `errorClass` option is a sibling of `rules`, not a child.

Comment: Under email I am now getting "Please enter a valid email", however I am not getting error messages for the other required form elements. Why would only email work? I can hit submit without any errors too.

Comment: Even after you fixed the misplaced `errorClass` option?

Comment: Yes, I added the errorClass before rules errorClass: "error", rules :{

Comment: I also just noticed that although the error messages are not showing up, I can not submit my form until said errors are fixed. i.e. passwords must match, otherwise I can not submit the form.

Comment: So that tells me that the messages are not working. A message for email isn't required, it's built in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84131/discussion-between-dylan-yelton-and-sparky).

Comment: That tells me you've simply broken the plugin... if you can submit without errors, then validation plugin is not working at all.  You are getting an email error thanks to HTML5 validation already built into the browser because the email field is `type="email"`.  Put `debug: true` as another `.validate()` option and look at your console.

Comment: Getting errors in the console now. <input id="name" class="form-control" type="name" placeholder="Enter your full name"> has no name assigned
jquery.....min.js (line 4)
<input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Enter email"> has no name assigned
jquery.....min.js (line 4)
<input id="pwd" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Enter password"> has no name assigned
jquery.....min.js (line 4)
<input id="pwdcnf" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Enter password"> has no name assigned
jquery.....min.js (line 4)

Comment: ***"has no `name` assigned"*** ~ That error is telling you exactly what I posted in [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31601451/594235).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an email error thanks to HTML5 validation already built into the browser thanks to `type="email"` on the `email` field.

**The plugin is not working because none of your fields contain a `name` attribute.**  A unique `name` attribute on each input is mandatory for this plugin to work.  It's how it keeps track of everything.

Also within your `rules` object, those names are supposed to correspond to each `name` attribute, not each `id`.

```
$('#registerform').validate({
    errorClass: "error",
    rules:{      
        'email': {   // <- this is the NAME attribute
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        'pwd': {     // <- this is the NAME attribute
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        'pwdcnf': {  // <- this is the NAME attribute
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    }, ....
```

HTML:

```
<input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">

<input name="pwd" type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">

<input name="pwdcnf" type="password" class="form-control" id="pwdcnf" placeholder="Enter password">
```

Comment: Oh, wow! Thanks a lot, Sparky! I did not see this comment of yours. This finally works! That took longer than I expected. At least now I know. Thumbs up for you!

Answer (score 2):

I think Bootstrap js may need jQuery as a dependency.

Try changing the order of your js file loading from so Bootstrap comes after jQuery.

```
<!--LOAD JQUERY-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<!--LOAD THIS FILE AFTER JQUERY-->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

On the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) website it says:

> **Plugin dependencies**
>   Some plugins and CSS components depend on other plugins. If you include plugins individually, make sure to check for these dependencies in the docs. **Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files). Consult our bower.json to see which versions of jQuery are supported**.